# How to use menu bar at the top via mouse?

Tags: terminal-emacs, mouse, menu-bar

I am opening emacs in `--no-window-system` mode and I switched `xterm-mouse-mode` on. Mouse clicks within a buffer work. However, I want the menu at the top of the window to open when I click on it.

I.e., when I click on `File`, I want the dropdown menu to show up the list with the options to open a file or to save the current buffer and so on.

What happens actually instead is that on the right half of the shell window a new buffer opens, showing a message like the one visible here: [image: like the one visible here].

How can I get the menu bar at the top of emacs to work as I expect it? I want the ordinary behaviour from all other "normal" GUI editors, which do not operate on the command line. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

> I want the ordinary behaviour from all other "normal" GUI editors

But you're *not* running it as a GUI editor, you're running in a terminal.

When `menu-bar-mode` is enabled (as it is for you), you can type <kbd><f10></kbd> to open the menus, and then navigate with the keyboard.

Or you can use the menus regardless by typing <kbd>M-`</kbd>

You may be able to get some mouse interaction by enabling `xterm-mouse-mode` in Emacs, but that won't necessarily do what you want for the menus. (In my case clicking on the menu names triggers the <kbd>M-`</kbd> behaviour for that menu.)

Comment: So there is no way to use the top menu completely by the mouse?

Comment: I don't know. The fact that `xterm-mouse-mode` exists and is able to detect clicks on the specific menu toolbar items, combined with the fact that the menu UI opened by `<f10>` is otherwise what you're after, does make me think that it may be possible to combine those two things to get the result you're looking for. I haven't looked into that myself, though.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, there are two different ways to show TTY menus:

- either `tmm-menubar` (the "ugly" menu),
- or `popup-menu` (the "nicer" menu).

It appears `<f10>` calls `popup-menu` by default, but this is customizable if ever we want to downgrade this to `tmm-menubar`:

> ```
> tty-menu-open-use-tmm is a variable defined in menu-bar.el.gz.
>
> Value
> nil
>
>
> Documentation
> If non-nil, <f10> on a TTY will invoke tmm-menubar.
>
> If nil, <f10> will drop down the menu corresponding to the
> first (leftmost) menu-bar item; you can select other items by typing
> C-f, C-b, <right> and <left>.
>
> This variable was added, or its default value changed, in Emacs 24.4.
> ```

Anyway, it's feasible to come up with a lisp solution to have `<mouse-1>` behave the same.

Here is a proof of concept, inspired by [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/50483/19818) by [@npostavs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/5296/npostavs), itself inspired by `menu-bar.el`:

```lisp
(defun menu-bar-get-minimal-x (menu-symbol x y)
  (let ((xx (- x 1)))
    (if (< xx tty-menu--initial-menu-x)
        x
      (if (equal (menu-bar-menu-at-x-y xx y (selected-frame)) menu-symbol)
          (menu-bar-get-minimal-x menu-symbol xx y)
        x))))

(defun menu-bar-open-x-y (mouse-event)
  (interactive "e")
  (pcase mouse-event
    (`(mouse-1 (,_ menu-bar (,x . ,y) . ,_))
     (let ((menu (menu-bar-menu-at-x-y x y)))
       (popup-menu (or
                    (lookup-key-ignore-too-long
                     global-map (vector 'menu-bar menu))
                    (lookup-key-ignore-too-long
                     (current-local-map) (vector 'menu-bar menu))
                    (cdar (minor-mode-key-binding (vector 'menu-bar menu)))
                    (mouse-menu-bar-map))
                   (posn-at-x-y (menu-bar-get-minimal-x menu x y) y nil t)
                   nil t)))
    (_ (message "unsupported event %S" (car mouse-event)))))

(define-key global-map (kbd "<menu-bar> <mouse-1>") 'menu-bar-open-x-y)
```