# Replace clicking a menu bar option from M-` to f10 behavior

Tags: terminal-emacs, mouse, menu-bar

When I click on `File` I want to see
[image: f10]
and not
[image: M-`]

What can I change to provide this functionality? [This question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32490/how-to-use-menu-bar-at-the-top-via-mouse) didn't really get the right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd><kbd>f1</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd></kbd> (`describe-key-briefly`) works for mouse clicks and menu items too.  So hit <kbd><kbd>f1</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd></kbd>, click on the menu bar, and you'll see `<menu-bar> <mouse-1> at that spot runs the command tmm-menubar-mouse`.  Whereas <kbd><kbd>f1</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>f10</kbd></kbd> says `<f10> runs the command menu-bar-open`.  So to rebind:

```el
(define-key global-map (kbd "<menu-bar> <mouse-1>") 'menu-bar-open)
```

> Clicking on a different option than File will still open the file menu

Right, `menu-bar-open` doesn't check xy location of the mouse click.  Looking at the code of `menu-bar-open` I came up with this:

```el
(defun menu-bar-open-xy (mouse-event)
  (interactive "e")
  (pcase mouse-event
    (`(mouse-1 (,_ menu-bar (,x . ,y) . ,_))
     (let ((menu (menu-bar-menu-at-x-y x y)))
       (popup-menu (or
                    (lookup-key-ignore-too-long
                     global-map (vector 'menu-bar menu))
                    (lookup-key-ignore-too-long
                     (current-local-map) (vector 'menu-bar menu))
                    (cdar (minor-mode-key-binding (vector 'menu-bar menu)))
                    (mouse-menu-bar-map))
                   (posn-at-x-y x y nil t) nil t)))
    (_ (error "unexpected event %S" mouse-event))))

(define-key global-map (kbd "<menu-bar> <mouse-1>") 'menu-bar-open-xy)
```

The X co-ordinate is a bit off though, not clear why.

> Clicking on File once file is open doesn't close the menu, just reopens it

Yeah, I'm not sure how to fix that.  I guess that explains why this isn't the default in Emacs yet...

Comment: This works pretty well but there are two glaring problems:
- Clicking on a different option than `File` will still open the file menu
- Clicking on `File` once file is open doesn't close the menu, just reopens it

Comment: @Soren see edit, 2nd problem seems quite tough

Answer (score 0):

That's a great question.

[npostavs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/5296/npostavs)'s [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/50483/19818) is really nice, but has a subtle drawback:
the x offset of the popup menu does not matches that of the initially-shown menu name.

So, here is a snippet that fixes this issue:
it adds a small recursive function in lisp — given the [main function at stake](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/009236502ef960c18e0e0070fdbc4fe6e4adc969/src/menu.c#L1049) is only available in C code otherwise!

```lisp
(defun menu-bar-get-minimal-x (menu-symbol x y)
  (let ((xx (- x 1)))
    (if (< xx tty-menu--initial-menu-x)
        x
      (if (equal (menu-bar-menu-at-x-y xx y (selected-frame)) menu-symbol)
          (menu-bar-get-minimal-x menu-symbol xx y)
        x))))

(defun menu-bar-open-x-y (mouse-event)
  (interactive "e")
  (pcase mouse-event
    (`(mouse-1 (,_ menu-bar (,x . ,y) . ,_))
     (let ((menu (menu-bar-menu-at-x-y x y)))
       (popup-menu (or
                    (lookup-key-ignore-too-long
                     global-map (vector 'menu-bar menu))
                    (lookup-key-ignore-too-long
                     (current-local-map) (vector 'menu-bar menu))
                    (cdar (minor-mode-key-binding (vector 'menu-bar menu)))
                    (mouse-menu-bar-map))
                   ;; this line differs from the initial answer
                   (posn-at-x-y (menu-bar-get-minimal-x menu x y) y nil t)
                   nil t)))
    (_ (error "unexpected event %S" mouse-event))))

(define-key global-map (kbd "<menu-bar> <mouse-1>") 'menu-bar-open-x-y)
```